# C# directive for code to run only when working on localhost

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there any directive in C# that runs a code (server side code) only when the application runs on localhost and ignores it on production (not the debug true or false)?

It can be something that reads a web.config appsettings variable, if it's true, run the code, if it's false, ignore it (just an idea).

Comment: Haven't you answered your own question?

Comment: I'm with James. If you're looking for validation about whether your idea will work or not, I'd say it would. The question is... do you *really* want it to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (Request.IsLocal)
  // Do magic
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to run your web.config option:

```
if (Boolean.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["runDebugCode"]))
// Do magic
```

... but this will run for all users of your web application, regardless of client they are connecting from.

The `Request.IsLocal` test will pass only for those clients connecting from the same machine as the web host.